# How can I get a List of objects using Unirest for Java?

Tags: java, unirest

I can use Unirest to get an object of my own class like this:

```
HttpResponse<Item> itemResponse = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080/item").asObject(Item.class);
```

I can also set the type parameter to `List`, which does give me a list of hash maps, but I'd like to get a list of items instead. Is this possible?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't know if you're still waiting for an answer, but you should use an array.
Like this;

```
HttpResponse<Item[]> itemResponse = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080/item").asObject(Item[].class);
```

Comment: Well this was for a class last semester, but I appreciate your help. I'm sure it will help someone else too!

Answer (score 5):

Besides @scuro's answer, you can also get a list of objects from a response like this:

```
List<Item> items = Unirest.get("http://localhost:8080/item")
              .asObject(new GenericType<List<Item>>(){})
              .getBody();
```

From [Unirest Docs.](http://kong.github.io/unirest-java/#responses)

Comment: Just a note that `GenericType<T>` is Java EE and won't be available in a Java SE project. In this case, @scuro's response works.